# How can I make an icon hover together with text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I hover over a menu item, text pops up with an icon. When I hover over the icon, it moves to the top of the menu.

How can I make it so the icon moves to the top at the same time the text pops up?

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="icon_about"></i>
                <span class="title">About</span>
                <span class="description">Learn about us</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <i class="icon_work"></i>
                <span class="title">Work</span>
                <span class="description">See our work</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

jQuery

```
   $("ul#menu a").hover(function() {
           $(this).stop().animate({
               bottom: '0px'
           }, 1000);
       },
       function() {
           $(this).stop().animate({
               bottom: '-65px'
           }, 1000);
       });

   $("ul#menu a i").hover(function() {
           $(this).stop().animate({
               top: '0px'
           }, 1000);
       },
       function() {
           $(this).stop().animate({
               top: '20px'
           }, 1000);
       });
```

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle? This is most likely just a CSS problem.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by using the following jQuery:

```
      $("ul#menu a").hover(function() {
          $(this).stop().animate({
              bottom: '0px'
          }, 1000);
      },
      function() {
          $(this).stop().animate({
              bottom: '-65px'
          }, 1000);
      });

  $("ul#menu a").hover(function() {
          $(this).find("i").stop().animate({
              top: '0px'
          }, 500);
      },
      function() {
          $(this).find("i").stop().animate({
              top: '20px'
          }, 500);
      });
```